# Typescript and WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

When using Typescript and Visual Studio, the generated JavaScript code is wrapped in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (iife).

When using Typescript and WebStorm, the generated JavaScript code appears to put all of the objects in the global namespace.

Is there a way to set up WebStorm to *also* wrap the code in an iife so that all of those objects aren't on the global namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up WebStorm to also wrap the code in an iife so that all of those objects aren't on the global namespace?

You will have to show the `ts` code but two things:

Use an internal module:

```
module Foo{
     // Code here is in an IIFE
}
```

Or external modules and compile with `--module amd`:

```
export var foo = 123; // The whole file will be in an IIFE
```

More about external modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0